# How do I set a Selenium node's id with Selenium Grid Extras/json config files?

Tags: selenium, selenium-grid

I'm in the process of converting our Selenium Grid to use Selenium Grid Extras, which so far is looking great! But I'm having an issue where, before, our nodes would be represented by their machine name in the grid console (e.g. `id : http://SELENIUMXX:5555, OS : WINDOWS`), but now are only represented by their IP address (e.g. `id : http://x.x.x.x:5556, OS : WINDOWS`). Since the former are much easier to read, I'd like to know how to set the node ID attribute using SGE/json config files. The bat files for opening the nodes themselves are all dynamically constructed from the config files by SGE, so I can't set ID there.

I have a "friendlyHostName" parameter that it passes in, but that's only displayed in the console if you click over to the configuration tab.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a general way to do it so you don't have to change each one manually. In your config directory, set up a master node config file, with a `"host": "HOSTNAME",` line in the configuration per Krishnan Mahadevan's answer, and then run this batch file:

```
@echo off
set str1=   "host": "HOSTNAME",
set str2=   "host": 
set inputfile=node_master.json
set outputfile=[YOUR OUTPUT FILE]
for /d %%v in ("*") do ( 
  COPY %inputfile% %%v
  cd %%v
  >"%outputfile%" (
    for /f "usebackq delims=" %%A in (%inputfile%) do (
      if "%%A" equ "%str1%" (echo %str2% "%%v",) else (echo %%A)
    )
  )
  del %inputfile%
  cd ..
)
```

Answer (score 3):

You should find a node configuration file in the directory wherein you downloaded the Selenium Grid Extras jar. Open up that JSON file and add an attribute

```
"host": "MyMachineNameGoesHere"
```

under the key `"configuration"`

I decided to give Selenium Grid extras a whirl and here's how my complete node configuration file looks like

```
{
  "capabilities": [
    {
      "seleniumProtocol": "WebDriver",
      "browserName": "chrome",
      "maxInstances": 3,
      "version": "52",
      "platform": "MAC"
    }
  ],
  "configuration": {
    "proxy": "com.groupon.seleniumgridextras.grid.proxies.SetupTeardownProxy",
    "maxSession": 3,
    "port": 5555,
    "register": true,
    "unregisterIfStillDownAfter": 10000,
    "hubPort": 4444,
    "hubHost": "127.0.0.1",
    "host": "dragonlair.local",
    "nodeStatusCheckTimeout": 10000,
    "downPollingLimit": 0
  },
  "loadedFromFile": "node_5555.json"
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Went round and round on this with Selenium 3.141, trying to get json file to work.  Then stumbled on solution...

**Problem:** My Selenium 3.x "Grid Console" is not displaying the "id" (unique node name) that I specify in the json config file.

**Solution:** Don't use the json config file.  Instead, place "-id nodeName" in the commandline.

**Example:**

> java.exe -jar /pathToJar/selenium-server-standalone-3.141.59.jar -id
>   MyNodeName -role node -nodeConfig /pathToMyConfig/nodeConfig.json

Where "MyNodeName" is whatever unique name you want the Grid Console (website) to show your Selenium node as (instead of the default IP address).

**Summary:** In your command line, use "-id EnterNodeNameHere".

Don't know whether order matters...but I put -id before -role parm.